# Searching Entire Excel Worksheet and Deleteing all rows without a cell containing a phrase

Tags: vba, excel

I have merged several hundred XML files together, but I have a couple columns that have the a "CCI-" followed by some numbers in them.  I need to retain all the rows that contain columns with the letters CCI in them.  I tried this code, but it isn't working.  can someone give me a hand, please?  Thanks

```
Sub KeepOnlyAtSymbolRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


    Set rng = ws.Range("A3:E70000")

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="CCI*"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    ' turn off the filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: if you _"need to retain all the rows that contain columns with the letters CCI in them."_ then change `Criteria1:="CCI*"` to `Criteria1:="<>CCI*"`

Comment: CCI is not in the same column throughout.

Comment: Changing "CCI*" to "<>CCI*" deletes every row except row 3.

Comment: I didin't get that "CCI" could be found in different columns. see my answer for a possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop through all columns to exclude cells with "CCI"

to stick to your original code, you could adopt:

```
Sub KeepOnlyAtSymbolRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


    Set rng = ws.Range("A3:E70000")
    Dim col As Range

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
        For Each col In .Columns
            .AutoFilter Field:=col.Column, Criteria1:="<>CCI*"
        Next
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    ' turn off the filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

While a refactoring could be:

```
Option Explicit

Sub KeepOnlyAtSymbolRows()
    Dim col As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("E3", .cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| row 3 must be "header" one
            For Each col In .Columns
                .AutoFilter Field:=col.Column, Criteria1:="<>CCI*"
            Next
             If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off the filters
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @SeanKirkpatrick, here you see two different codes for the same solution: the first keeping as close as possibile to your original one, while the second showing some refactoring to make it more robust (especially with the `If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(...` part, that makes sure you delete something if only that something exists). If it solves your question you may want to mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you

Comment: User3698756-  I am getting an AutoFilter method of Range class failed error.

Comment: check the last code: I originally wrote "Sheet11" instead of "Sheet1". Be sure to use the name of the sheet you actually need

Comment: @SeanKirkpatrick, if Diego's code worked then you have "CCI" occurrences in first column only

Comment: There are no occurrences in the first column at all.  I did change your code to sheet 1 prior to running it.  when I step through the code, it is hitting on the autofilter line.

Comment: I mean that with such a code as `.AutoFilter Field:=col.Column, Criteria1:="<>CCI*"` you're caring about first column only, which is not  what you wrote with _"CCI is not in the same column throughout"_. As for the _"AutoFilter method of Range class failed error"_ I did test both my codes without errors. Which is the value of `col.Column` when you hit it?

Comment: your code works as well, but for some reason I have to scroll to the bottom of the workbook to get it to work.  Not sure why.

Comment: Glad to know that. What do you mean for _"scroll to the bottom of the workbook"_? And what code are you using: the 1st or the 2nd?

Comment: For some reason I can't get it to work when I am at the top of the worksheet say cell A1 selected.  Not sure why because it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt work because your making the opposite autofilter. it should be:

```
Sub KeepOnlyAtSymbolRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


    Set rng = ws.Range("A3:E70000")

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*CCI**"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    ' turn off the filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: @SeanKirkpatrick in comments you wrote _"CCI is not in the same column throughout"_: if this holds true then this code wouldn't work since it only filters 1st column

Comment: @user3598756 that's not the situation, since the autofilter is applied to `rng` variable (A3:E7000). the code says that the criteria should be looked in the first column (field 1) of that range.

Comment: that's precisely what I wrote, your code is filtering `rng` first column only. While SeanKirkpatrick  wrote _"CCI is not in the same column throughout"_. He must have been wrong but to shy to admit it

Comment: @user3598756 possible, but it's just a little mistake that gladly you pointed out.

Comment: then my first comment under the question did it, already. but Sean didn't even tried it and wrote _"CCI is not in the same column throughout"_. You see, the actual _mistake_ is considering other people help as due and their efforts in it as worthless. too bad you can only see that once it's done

Comment: I am not sure why the negative comments.  CCI is not in the same column.  Both your code worked and I appreciate it.  I am new to dealing with coding like this and am trying to learn.  All I now is that the code from both of you worked.